# while running deploy it is showing problem in maria db

Tags: mariadb, openstack

I am running deploy command after bootstrap and precheck command and it is showing an error.

I have delete mariadb container and again downloaded it but it is showing this error:

> kolla-ansible -i ./all-in-one deploy
>
> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["docker", "update", "--restart", "no", "mariadb"], "delta": "0:00:00.061945", "end": "2019-09-18 00:10:33.056106", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-09-18 00:10:32.994161", "stderr": "Error response from daemon: No such container: mariadb", "stderr_lines": ["Error response from daemon: No such container: mariadb"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

Comment: how do you solve it

Comment: I haven't solved it yet, trying to find the error

Answer (score 5):

It is not enough to remove the container, you have to remove the mariadb volume too, then the whole container gets bootstrapped on next deploy:

docker volume rm mariadb

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue in my multinode setup (Ubuntu18) of kolla stable/stein. 
Spent 10 days to figure out what caused it. 
Finally what worked for me is written as steps below:

1. Remove all kolla images
2. Stop docker service
3. Clean tmp and containers folders (Parent folder is /var/lib/docker)
4. Start docker service
5. Deploy again everything worked fine

Hope these steps will help you too.
Regards,
San